# What is the meaning of UNCLEAN state in iptables

Tags: iptables

What is the meaning of UNCLEAN state in iptables?

Example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate UNCLEAN -j DROP
```

This actually gives me an error, but there should exist an unclean state.

Moreover, what is the difference and connection with INVALID state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UNCLEAN :**

- The `UNCLEAN` match takes no options and requires no more than
  explicitly loading it when you want to use it. Note that this option
  is regarded as experimental and may not work at all times, nor will
  it take care of all unclean packets or problems. The unclean match
  tries to match packets that seem malformed or unusual, such as
  packets with bad headers or checksums and so on. This could be used
  to `DROP` connections and to check for bad streams, for example;
  however, you should be aware that it could possibly break legal
  connections.
- As a side note : It was removed a while ago (sorry, don't recall exactly when, but I
  believe it was with the start of the 2.6.x tree). They cited the fact
  that it was not being used properly and the implementation wasn't
  what they wanted anyway. Something to that effect. It should be in
  one of the 2.6.x changelogs I think.

**INVALID :** Referred [from](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/resource_files/firewalls/IPTables-Tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#MATCHES)

- The `INVALID` state means that the packet can't be identified or that it does not have any state. This may be due to several reasons, such as the system running out of memory or ICMP error messages that do not respond to any known connections. Generally, it is a good idea to DROP everything in this state.
- Rule with `INVALID` state will drop all packets with invalid headers or checksums, invalid TCP flags, invalid ICMP messages (such as a port unreachable when we did not send anything to the host), and out of sequence packets which can be caused by sequence prediction or other similar attacks. The `DROP` target will drop a packet without any response, contrary to REJECT which politely refuses the packet. We use `DROP` because there is no proper `REJECT` response to packets that are `INVALID`, and we do not want to acknowledge that we received these packets.